# How to set default state for an object when using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I set a default value for an object using `useState` in a React function component, then my control linking to a field in that object does not get updated state values for a field in the object.

See this example:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Form} from 'react-bootstrap'

function BrokenForm(props) {

    const defaultO = {
        field1: "this gets stuck in state - or so it looks ..."
    }

    const [o, setO] = useState(defaultO)          // Setting a default here causes trouble
    const [x, setX] = useState('simple value')    // This works as expected

    const onChangeField1 = (event) => {
        let newO = o
        newO.field1 = event.target.value
        setO(newO)
    }

    const onChangeX = (event) => setX(event.target.value)

    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Label>Object Field1</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control value={o.field1} onChange={onChangeField1} />

            <Form.Label>Simple Value</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control value={x} onChange={onChangeX} />
        </Form>
    )
}
```

The first form control never updates with the value of `o.field1` even though the `onChangeField1` function looks like it has updated it.

However, if I initialize the value of `o` with a null object, everything works fine:

```
const [o, setO] = useState[{}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try this :`useState({...defaultO})`

Comment: @Eldar - I tried that.  Same behaviour.

Comment: Since you already solved your problem, I recommend you to subscribe to this series:

https://justjavascript.com

This course is very helpful, it'll help you understand these stuff under the hood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there in onChangeField1 you are not immutably cloning the state and that could be one of the reasons for the issue.When you assign an object to another in js it gives it a reference so

```
let newO=o;
```

It is just passing a reference

What you should do instead is

```
let newO={...o}
```

This will immutably clone the state.

Let me know if you face any issues even after this,

Comment: Yep - that has fixed it.

Comment: Glad it helped you.Please approve this as the correct answer and upvote it